# Is there a way to close all instances of nested core-dropdowns?

Tags: dart, polymer

I created a custom dart polymer component with a nested core-dropdown component.

```dart
<a id="row-options-button" class="optionsBtn" href="#" style=""
            title="Options" on-click="{{ openDropdown }}" relative>
             <i id="ellipsisIcon" class="icon fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i>
             <core-dropdown id="optionsDropDown" class="colored" layered="true" autoCloseDisabled="false">
                 <core-selector single valueattr="label">
                    <core-item label="Display for 8 seconds"></core-item>
                 </core-selector>
             </core-dropdown>
         </a>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**The problem:**
If I create multiple instances of this component, I manage to open the dropdown but then it remains open despite clicking on another instance of the same component, or sometimes another element.

I'm looking for a solution to close all open dropdowns except for the one I just clicked on. My guess is that it'll be hard since they all have their own shadow dom...I'm hoping someone has ran into this issue before.

Comment: Looks like a bug in the `core-dropdown` element to me.

Comment: Thanks @GünterZöchbauer, I thought about traversing all the shadow doms to find instances and close them, but this is crazy once the potential numbers grow.

Comment: You can use the `* /deep/ core-dropdown` selector to get them all at once.

Comment: Right, but that's just to dress them up with CSS correct?
I tried a `document.querySelecorAll('core-dropdown')` but this didn't return all instances.

Comment: Use the selector from my prev comment instead in querySelector

Comment: I'm sorry Gunter, but I don't follow your use of the * /deep/ core-dropdown, could you elaborate a bit more?
Should the newly clicked instance of the component try to use your example? or call something on the parent doc to close them all and then use the * /deep/ etc?

Comment: You could add this to your component. If the dropdown is opened, look up all dropdowns on the page and ensure all but the current get closed. I would need to build a sample project to provide more concrete information how to do it exactly.